# Prepositions usage of from and in

Tags: prepositions

**He asked me yesterday whether anyone from our class is participating**.

My doubt is whether we should use "from our class " or "in our class".

Thankyou

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**In** is fine as you are talking about an individual who is part of the class.

**From** is often used when referring to selecting an item/individual out of a group. It doesn't mean that they are actually being removed from the group, but it emphasizes that they are being singled out or that they are doing something beyond the borders of the group.

For activities or properties *internal to* the class/group of people comprising the class, **in** is usually better than **from**: *Is anyone **from** the class over 10 years old?* and *Is anyone **from** the class having trouble with the homework?* sound a bit odd.

But when talking about somebody who is representing the group externally, **from** can emphasize this: e.g., *Is anyone **from** my son's class performing in the show?* on the assumption that the show is not specific to one class. (**In** would be fine here too.)

Answer (score 1):

Both would be fine.

‘From our class’ would mean the same as ‘in our class’ in this case.